# Extracting Width/Height Dimensions from EMF Image Files

Tags: windows, perl, vector-graphics, .emf

I maintain a small Perl library that extracts width/height from images, for people who want that functionality without using a larger, more generalized library. I've been asked if I can support the Windows EMF format. However, I haven't had much luck with my Google-fu in trying to find a good specification of the format, or better yet example code (in any language). I'm looking for either a decent spec on the format, or examples of reading/parsing the files. As usually, and and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a (working) EMF parser on CPAN yet -- there is a placeholder version as [Data::ParseBinary::Graphics::EMF](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::ParseBinary::Graphics::EMF), where I'm sure the author would be grateful if you suplied him with some working patches :)

Answer (score 12):

The official specification can be downloaded directly from MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230514(PROT.10).aspx.

It will take some time to read and understand, but it should definitely be doable if you have worked with binary file formats before.

But please notice that EMF is a (pseudo-) vector image format, and so images can be scaled to any size. But there might be a *default* width and height. In particular, there really should be a well-defined aspect ratio.

## Update

I *think* that the width (in pixels) of the metafile is the 5th cardinal of the file, and the height (in pixels) the 6th cardinal. In a *typical* case. At least this might be a decent starting point for you.

I just created a sample EMF file, which starts

```
01 00 00 00 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
ae 01 00 00 75 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The fifth cardinal is AE010000 which, due to the byte little-endianness, is 000001AE in hex, i.e. 430 in decimal. The sixth cardinal is 75010000, i.e. 00000175 in hex or 373 in decimal. Hence I get the dimension to be 430×373 sq. pixels. Paint reports 432×374 sq. pixels.

If I get more time left, I will study the file format more extensively. But at least I hope this might be a starting point for you.

## Update 2

The third and forth 32-bit integers are apparently the left and top coordinates of the image, in logical units, respectively, while the fifth and sixth 32-bit integers are the right and bottom coordinates. In most cases `(top, left) = (0, 0)`, and then my text above is correct (i.e. then `width = right`, `height = top` coordinate).

If `(top, left) <> (0, 0)`, then, naturally, `width = right - left` and `height = bottom - top`.

Now this is probably not the whole story; if you compare the obtained numbers with the ones reported by Paint you will get small deviations. So *To be continued...*.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Andreas Rejbrand's researches I've made the code in Python that gets the sizes of EMF file:

```
with open("img.emf", "rb") as f:
    f.read(16)
    w1, w2 = f.read(1).hex(), f.read(1).hex()
    f.read(2)
    h1, h2 = f.read(1).hex(), f.read(1).hex()

width  = int(str(w2) + str(w1), 16) * 762 # I've no idea why is '762' but it works this way
height = int(str(h2) + str(h1), 16) * 762
```

I belive it can be implemented in Perl as well if it's able to read bytes.

Here is how it works in a real task: [Unable to insert EMF into Word using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67672120/unable-to-insert-emf-into-word-using-python)